# Copying Character Pointer into another Character Pointer in C Without strcpy

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some issues copying the contents of one pointer to another. I'm not able to get the contents of `* s` to copy into `* a`. If I remove the bump for  `* a`, it copies only the last character from `s`. Also the use of any string library functions or any array notation isn't allowed. Sorry if the formatting is poor, this is my first post. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 char* copy( char *s )
 {
     char *a = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*length(s));
     if (s == NULL)
     {
         printf("ERROR: OUT OF MEMORY\n" );
         return 0;
     }
     while( *s != '\0' )
     {
         *a = *s;
         s++;
         a++;
     }

     *a = '\0';
     return a;
 }
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc, it adds nothing.  `char *a =  malloc(sizeof(char)*length(s));` is fine.  Also, your test should be `if (a == NULL)` (not `s`)

Comment: what is `length` ?

Comment: @M.M, probably just his own `strlen` function.

Comment: @RoadRunner in that case, the malloc would be too short

Comment: @M.M Could he just not use `strdup()`?

Comment: `strdup` is not a standard C function. And he said he wasn't allowed to use any string library functions anyway.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition.

Comment: the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 in the standard, and multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: strdup is broken It's not available without some configuration, and even then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never modify the value of a pointer you have allocated.  If you do that, may lose track of the address and be unable to free it.

```
char* copy( const char *s )
{
    char *a = malloc(length(s)+1);
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        return NULL;
    }

    char *c = a;
    while( *s != '\0' )
    {
        *c = *s;
        s++;
        c++;
    }

    *c = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

Very simple test:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *s = "this is a test string";
    char *a;

    if (NULL != (a = copy(s))) {
        printf("The copy is: %s\n", a);
        free(a);
    }
}
```

Results in:

> The copy is: this is a test string

Comment: BLUEPIXY may jump on me for suggesting this, but if you do this: `char * const a = malloc(length(s)+1)` the compiler will warn you if you try to modify it before you return it.

Comment: After making these changes, *c is filled with the proper value but *a is not and empty space is being returned.

Comment: @Makthe2nd That's odd behavior since both c and a point to the same piece of memory.  You sure there is no typo?

Comment: @Makthe2nd be careful you're freeing any memory you're allocating.

Comment: the value 0 is not necessarily the same as NULL. Strongly suggest, when `malloc()` fails, use the following two lines: `{ perror( "malloc failed" );  return NULL; }` as this will output the reason the OS thinks the `malloc()` failed, along with the text you supplied And then returns a char *, as it is expected to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I wasn't freeing the memory and I was still bumping the old pointer. It is now working properly!